# Computing $\int_B x^2y^3$ over $1 \leq xy \leq 2$ and $x \leq y \leq 4x$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let B be the portion of the first quadrant in $\Bbb R^2$ lying between the hyperbolas $xy=1, xy=2$ and lines $y=x, y=4x$. Evaluate $$\int _Bx^2y^3.$$ Hint: set $x=u/v$ and $y=uv$.

First, I substituted the $u$'s and $v$'s and got values for $u$ and $v$. However, I do not know how to proceed further. Can someone please help me to use Change of Variables theorem to finish it? My idea was just to substitute $u$'s and $v$'s into the integral and give them the values I have got from finding where the functions cross. But I am not sure. The answer I got was $1$. It is the first time I am doing these so I am not good at it yet. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What limits did you get on $u$ and $v$? And how is $du ~dv$ related to $dx~dy$?

Comment: I got $u^2=2, u^2=1$ and $v^2=1, v^2=4$

Comment: @Psycho ...and the trasnformation's Jacobian??

Comment: @Psycho Your transformed limits are correct; since you are in the first quadrant, you just want the positive square-roots, which give you a rectangle in the $ \ uv-$ plane.  The Jacobian is essential, as it helps reduce the transformed integral into something simple -- and _separable!_  (But I believe the result for the integral is not 1 ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $x\le y \le 4x $ we conclude $x \le 4x$ so $0\le x$ and therefore also $0 \le y$. This and $1 \le xy $ implies $0< x,y$, so the domain lies in the open first quadrant. Here is a picture of $B$:

[image]

From $x = u/v$ and $y= uv$, with $u,v>0$ get $u = \sqrt{xy}$ and $v=\sqrt{y/x}$. Moreover, the domain for $(u,v)$ is the rectangle $R:=\{1\le u \le \sqrt{2},1 \le v \le 2\}$

The transformation $(u,v) \mapsto (x,y)=(u/v, uv)$ has the jacobian matrix

$$J(u,v)\left( \begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{v^2} & -\frac{u}{v^2} \\ v & u \end{array} \right )$$
with determinant $\det J(u,v) =\frac{2u}{v}$. Now we apply the change of variable formula

$$\int_B f(x,y) dx dy= \int_R f(u/v, uv)\, | \det J(u,v)|\, du dv$$
For $f(x,y) = x^2 y^3$ we have $f(u/v, uv)\, | \det J(u,v)|= (u/v)^2 (u v)^3 2 u/v = 2 u^6$. Therefore the integral equals
$$\int_R 2 u^6 \, du dv= \int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}2 u^6 \cdot 1 du= \ldots = -\frac{2}{7} + \frac{16 \sqrt{2}}{7}=2.94677\ldots$$